# Warlock's Shadow Legion

Tags: dnd-4e, warlock, powers

Shadow Legion<sup>[[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=13901)]</sup> (Heroes of Shadow p75) creates a conjuration for each enemy in the area of effect, which each make an attack against the enemy it was created for. Great, that all makes sense.

However, the conjurations last until the end of the encounter. Do they continue to attack the creatures they were created next to? Do they make opportunity attacks? Can they chase their target across the map? Can they be attacked? What do they do when their target dies?

The power says the conjurations are the same size as their target creature, so I assume they occupy their space. (Then again, enemies take necrotic damage at the end of their turn for each conjuration adjacent to them *or in their space*...) However, since the power doesn't expressly state that they count as allies, I assume you can't use them for flanking, correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the power doesn't give them the ability to attack after the initial one, and by default conjurations can't attack[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=62) they cannot make any sort of attacks. The power also doesn't give them the ability to move, so they stay where they are. The power doesn't give them any defenses so they cannot be attacked. The power doesn't say anything happens when a given targets shadow dies, so it sticks around.

The power doesn't say it occupies it space so it doesn't occupy squares, but it is in squares for determining what gets hit by the 5 damage every turn (I know this sounds kinda weird, not occupying squares mostly means that other things can enter the square without any issues). The power doesn't say that the conjurations can provide flanking so they don't.

Basically after they make their initial attack they do nothing but ping enemies for being too close.

For some examples of conjurations that can do the things you are asking about there is [Twilight Assassin](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=9426), who can make attacks, move, occupy its space and flank with you (but not your allies), and [Shaped Consciousness](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=13300), which can move, occupy its space and take damage.